# MySQL dump crash unexpectedly with (secure) option --login-path

Tags: mysql, security, command-line, windows-server-2012

We have a script on testing server for backup mysql database from production server, it has been working fine for a long time:

```
mysqldump -h prod_server_ip -u user -ppswd --lock-tables=false database_name > path_to_file\database_name.sql
```

But now we would like to use more secure script via *.mylogin.cnf*, so we used *mysql_config_editor* and created record in *.mylogin.cnf*. All steps were ok, until we have executed the script:

```
mysqldump --login-path=prod_server --lock-tables=false database_name > path_to_file\database_name.sql
```

When we execute a script, mysqldump crashes after some seconds unexpectedly = dumpfile is not complete (the size of this dump file is various). So we turn on option --verbose a we have seen last rows:

```
-- Retrieving table structure for table a...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table b...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
*-- Disconnecting from localhost...*
```

There is only log: Disconnecting from localhost... I notice that first script with user and password works still perfect.

Mysql version is 5.6.28.

Comment: How much data do you intend to backup, GiB, TiB?. Does the problem reproduce with a small amount of data, for example, 1 MiB?.

Comment: This database has approximately 600 MB, after about 130MB it will happen disconnecting. The first script with user and password had never problem with sizes of databases...